# How to update log file size in db2

Tags: sql, db2

How to update the log file size in db2. I was trying to run this command in dbeaver but non of these works

```
UPDATE DATABASE CONFIGURATION USING LOGFILSIZ 4096 LOGPRIMARY 50 LOGSECOND 10;

UPDATE DATABASE CONFIGURATION FOR <MY_DBNAME> USING LOGFILSIZ 4096;

UPDATE DB CFG FOR <MY_DBNAME> USING LOGFILSIZ 4096;
```

Answer (score 1):

DBeaver (and similar tools) let you run SQL against databases.

But 'update database configuration' is **NOT** sql,  instead it is a **command** understood only by the Db2 tool known as the command-line-processor (db2 clp).    That means, you need to give these commands to the Db2 clp , which you can do in two different ways (a) directly at the command shell   or (b) indirectly via calling a stored procedure.

To use the command line shell (in db2cmd.exe on MS-Windows, or bash/ksh)

```
db2 update dbm cfg using ...

or 

db2 update db cfg using...`
```

You can do this either directly at the Db2-LUW server console, or you can do it from a suitably configured remote client that has the proper software (db2 fat client) already installed and configured and using suitably authorised credentials.

To use a stored procedure, you need to `CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD(....)`.
You can do that from DBeaver.
This is all explained in the free online documentation.
STUDY the DOCS before asking questions.
The link to the documentation showing examples is [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-update-database-manager-configuration-using-admin-cmd):
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-update-database-manager-configuration-using-admin-cmd
Remember that your authid must have the relevant authority/permissions for this to succeed, and some actions require the database to be reactivated before they become effective.

Study the documentation carefully!